# SmackException NoResponseException Android xmpp connection

Tags: android, xmpp

Hi I am creating a chat application. I want to read the data from the VCard> I am using the following code..

```
private VCard getVCard(String dialogId){

        VCard card = new VCard();
        ProviderManager.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp:x:update", new VCardProvider());
        try {
            card.load(ChatService.mConnection, dialogId);
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return card;
    }
```

Which is working some time, but now it is not working. I am facing the following error.

```
 org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: 
No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: 
IQReplyFilter: iqAndIdFilter (AndFilter: (OrFilter: (IQTypeFilter: type=error, IQTypeFilter: type=result), StanzaIdFilter: id=8DEYf-18)), : 
fromFilter (OrFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full): 919879879871@www.chatapp.com)).
 at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:229)
 at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:213)
 at org.jivesoftware.smackx.vcardtemp.VCardManager.loadVCard(VCardManager.java:125)
 at org.jivesoftware.smackx.vcardtemp.packet.VCard.load(VCard.java:575)
 at com.android.chat.ui.fragments.Homefragment.getVCard(Homefragment.java:618)
 at com.android.chat.ui.fragments.Homefragment.access$900(Homefragment.java:85)
 at com.android.chat.ui.fragments.Homefragment$DownloadContactList.insertIntoDB(Homefragment.java:672)
 at com.android.chat.ui.fragments.Homefragment$DownloadContactList.access$800(Homefragment.java:630)
 at com.android.chat.ui.fragments.Homefragment$DownloadContactList$1.onSuccess(Homefragment.java:647)
 at com.android.chat.ui.fragments.Homefragment$DownloadContactList$1.onSuccess(Homefragment.java:640)
 at com.android.chat.core.TCChatService.getChatDialogs(TCChatService.java:387)
 at com.android.chat.ui.fragments.Homefragment$DownloadContactList.doInBackground(Homefragment.java:640)
 at com.android.chat.ui.fragments.Homefragment$DownloadContactList.doInBackground(Homefragment.java:630)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Looks like the server is down, unreachable or the connection if awfully slow.

Comment: But I am able to access openfire....

Comment: But in openfire under session tab my presence not showing....

Comment: Do other apps requiring internet connection work?

Comment: Other apps working..

Comment: It seems like the server for whatever reason doesn't respond to vcard requests within 5 seconds. You might find the reason for that in the server log.

Comment: @legoscia It is working now. I didn't make any changes in code. So you are right.  Thanks for the response